# Apache Airflow DAG with single task

Tags: python, airflow

I'm newbie in Apache Airflow.
There are a lot of examples of basic DAGs in the Internet.
Unfortunately, I didn't find any examples of single-task DAG's.

Most of DAG's examples contain bitshift operator in the end of the .py script, which defines tasks order.
For example:

```
# ...our DAG's code...
task1 >> task2 >> task3
```

But what if my DAG has just a single task at the moment?
My question is - do I need to use this single task's name in the end of Python file?
Or if we have only 1 task in the scope, Airflow will handle it itself, and the last line of code below is redundant?

```
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
}
with DAG(
    'tutorial',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    tags=['example'],
) as dag:

    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='print_date',
        bash_command='date',
    )

    t1 # IS THIS LINE OF CODE NECESSARY?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is NO, you don't need to include the last line. You could also avoid the asignment of the variable `t1`, leaving the DAG like this:

```py
with DAG(
    'tutorial',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    tags=['example'],
) as dag:

    BashOperator(
        task_id='print_date',
        bash_command='date',
    )
```

The reason to perfom the assignment of an instance of an Operator (such as `BashOperator`), to a variable (called *Task* in this scope) is similiar to any other object in OOP. In your example there is no other "operation" perfomed over the `t1` variable (you are not reading it or consuming any method from it) so there no is no reason to declare it.

When starting with Airflow, I think is very clarifying to use the [DebugExecutor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/debug.html) to perform quick tests like this and understand how everything is working. If you are using VS Code you can find an example config file, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65719919/10569220).